# How to use PowerShell to switch default app (from pre-determined list) for a given file type? Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, ms-word, settings, file-type-associations

I frequently switch App to open PDFs and wish for shortcut. Without Admin Right, can PowerShell Script change default App from pre-determined list:

1. Open PowerShell Window
2. Show current Default
3. Press Enter if OK
4. Press Spacebar (non-graphical interface) to show next App in List
5. Press Enter to change Default
6. Above Script to show in Windows 10 Taskbar

As-Is, because Word is my only Enterprise Translation tool for PDF, it is very cumbersome for Word (when not default App) to open PDF.
[9 steps when Word is not default App](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-default-app-for-a-given-file-type/bb4663f8-2db2-47fc-a37f-3d5d1070612f)

Solutions that need Admin right

1. [Set default app for .PDF file extension to Adobe or Edge?](https://superuser.com/questions/1630002/set-default-app-for-pdf-file-extension-to-adobe-or-edge)
2. [How to Export and Import Custom Default App Associations for New Users in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8744-export-import-default-app-associations-new-users-windows.html)
3. [Add to default when File Extension is not listed](https://superuser.com/questions/1296013/how-do-i-set-a-default-app-for-an-extension-that-is-not-listed)

Answer (score 0):

File associations are kept in the windows registry, see [Changing Default File Associations in Windows 10 and 11](https://woshub.com/managing-default-file-associations-in-windows-10/) for more information. You can use group policy objects for deploying file associations or just customize the windows registry records on your own.

Comment: Smart default file associations will save me the labor of switching when default is not what I need. Currently, it is taking me 8 steps to open PDF with Word.